# Cordova and PushWoosh - with Android - No message in statusbar

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

I have just implemented pushwoosh in my Cordova project ... followed this guide http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/

and it works fine ... the only thing I don't get is that the push "message" is not shown in the phone statusbar., the LOGO and app title is show in the statusbar .. but NO text is shown... I don't get why ... anyone?

The push message is received perfect and the javascript is fired as well, but no text in the notification status bar .. only the logo and app title..

Comment: Did you try `var title = event.notification.message;` instead of `var title = event.notification.title;` inside the listener? just in case, try it.

Comment: Yep ... it's not that ... I think it must have something to do with the native code / eg. pushwoosh plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finalay.... Now i got it ... Stupid me ...

In the PushWoosh settings I have set the "PhoneGap Build (Generic)" setting ... Change this to  "Pushwoosh" and it works ;)